# If $\phi$ holds for all standard models of ZF and ZF proves this, then does ZF prove $\phi$?

Tags: logic, set-theory

I apologize if this is a nonsensical question.

Suppose $\phi$ holds in all standard models of ZF. Suppose further that ZF proves this. Then does ZF prove $\phi$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No (assuming there are standard models at all). $\operatorname{Con}\sf(ZF)$ is always true in standard models, and $\sf ZF$ proves that $\operatorname{Con}\sf(ZF)$ is always true in standard models. But of course that $\operatorname{Con}\sf(ZF)$ is not provable from $\sf ZF$ itself.

The reason is that standard models agree with the universe about the natural numbers, and therefore about basic arithmetic statements like the example above.

If there are *any* models of $\sf ZF$, then $\operatorname{Con}\sf (ZF)$ is true. And so, if there are no standard models at all, then vacuously, $\operatorname{Con}\sf (ZF)$ holds in all of them; and if there is a standard model, then $\operatorname{Con}\sf (ZF)$ is true in the universe, and therefore in the standard model. So indeed $\sf ZF$ proves that in any standard model of $\sf ZF$, $\operatorname{Con}\sf (ZF)$ must be true.

Comment: I'd be happy to hear about any complaints.

Comment: I **really** do not understand the downvote.  Please explain.

Comment: @Andreas: Am I missing something in the following implication, If there are no standard models, we're done; if there is a standard model, then Con(ZF) is true in the universe, and therefore it is true in the standard model.

Comment: You're right.  My mistake is that the alleged equivalence between "Con(ZF) holds in all standard models" and Con(ZF) tacitly assumed that the "all standard models" part isn't vacuous.  I'll delete my incorrect comment (since this one contains enough information to reconstruct it if anyone wants to).

Comment: @Andreas: Thanks, I wrote this answer immediately after waking up. I was worried I may have missed something.

Comment: I thought I was writing my first comment shortly before falling asleep, but apparently it was actually shortly after.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but: how exactly does "ZF proves that Con(ZF) is always true in standard models?" (I'm not the downvoter, by the way.)

Comment: @Noah: Funny, I went over this with Andreas who had the same complaint. See the first comment addressed to him. It either holds vacuously, or it just holds. Maybe I'll add that to the post, since it seems to confuse a lot of people who are up very early or very late. :-)

Comment: Hehe, I wondered what that was in response to. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand how you plan to formalise the notion of "standard model" in ZF, so I don't think the question or this answer is coherent. The question says "and ZF proves this", where "this" depends on the notion of a standard model.

Comment: @Rob: I don't understand the problem, really. "Standard model" is a transitive model, or one isomorphic to a transitive model. How can you *not* formalize this in $\sf ZF$? It is a model (a set $M$ and a binary relation $E$ on $M$) such that every axiom of $\sf ZF$ is true in $M$, and $E$ is *externally* well-founded, or $E=\in\restriction M$ if you prefer, or $E=\in\restriction M$ and $M$ is a transitive set. There, I formalized it.

Comment: @Rob: The point in my previous comment is that all three are "practically the same" since whatever notion you choose (well-founded, $\in$-based, or transitive and $\in$-based) is ultimately isomorphic, uniquely, to a transitive model. So as far as provability and true statements go, it *really* doesn't matter which way you chose to define the notion of "standard model".

Comment: Maybe I've been doing to much type theory. To me a "standard model" is one in which the power sets are the full power sets. (Essentially, to keep me happy you or the OP needs to say exactly what "standard model" means here.)

Comment: @Rob: That is too much type theory indeed. This is a standard term in [ZF-based] set theory. Yes, pun intended. To have a model with "full power sets", you have to have it as $V_\alpha$ for some $\alpha$, and that can also be formalized simply by saying that there exists some $\alpha$ such that $x\in M$ if and only if the von Neumann rank of $x$ is less than $\alpha$ (or that $M$ is isomorphic, uniquely, to such $V_\alpha$). Such $\alpha$ has to be a cardinal, of course, but not necessarily regular; they are called *Worldly Cardinals*.

Comment: @RobArthan "Full power sets" is irrelevant here. Con(ZFC) is a statement about integers and cannot be false in any model of ZFC whose integers are standard.

Comment: I am now very intrigued. Can you point me at some references for this use of "standard model", please.

Comment: @hot_queen: thanks, but at the moment I am trying to understand the use of the term "standard" in the original question.

Comment: @Rob: I have seen and heard it from many a set theorist. And since I'm just about to leave, actual citation from books and papers is too much, but [here's one example](http://mathoverflow.net/a/124723/7206) of someone else using that term.